# Unlimited vertical space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I'm working on a project that requires a ListView builder sadly when ever I try to put in that ListView builder this the error I get:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
lib\screens\questionScreen.dart:50
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#18955 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

here is my code:

```
Scaffold(
                body: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 120, 20, 50),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      questions[question.getListNumber()].soru,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 1,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          tileColor: Colors.white,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set `shrinkWrap: true` property and wrap the `ListView.builder` with an Expanded, it will solve everything, or if you have any fixed size for the `ListView.builder` wrap in a `SizedBox/Container` with the fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving infinite space to an unbounded widget. Your ListView is inside of the Column should be wrapped with a finite space widget such as container.

```
Scaffold(
                body: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 120, 20, 50),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      questions[question.getListNumber()].soru,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 1,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            tileColor: Colors.white,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ));
```